# Visual Studio Not Finding 'vulkan-1.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, vulkan

I read [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#comment-4591494399) to try to set up Vulkan in Visual Studio. I got to the very end, compiled, and got this:

[image]

A few more screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I'm using version 1.1.114.0 while the tutorial is using 1.1.77.0, which may be at the root of the issue. However, I have not been able to find another tutorial showing how to set Vulkan up like this. How do I get Vulkan to work in Visual Studio?

Comment: It is a basic "file not found" error, none of the screenshots are relevant to this mishap.  The tutorial doesn't omit the required step to tell the linker in what directory to look for the file.

Comment: The last screenshot at least establishes that he's not using a fully qualified path for the vulkan library.  That, along with the tutorial link and the error screenshot gives enough information to make a reasonable guess as to what he missed when following the tutorial.  The tutorial itself doesn't include step numbers and is just a wall of screenshots and single line instructions, so I can see how easy it would be to skip over a step without realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must have missed a step in the tutorial.  Specifically, look for the text

> Next, open the editor for library directories under `Linker -> General`

in the linked tutorial page.

In the linker *Input* tab, either use a complete path to the Vulkan library (for example `C:\VulkanSDK\1.1.101.0\Lib\vulkan-1.lib`) or in the *General* tab, add the location of the library (for example `C:\VulkanSDK\1.1.101.0\Lib` to the *Additional Library Directories* entry).

If you can express the values in terms of an environment variable, then you'd want to use either `VULKAN_SDK` or `VK_SDK_PATH`, which in the above examples would resolve to `C:\VulkanSDK\1.1.101.0`.  That way when you update your Vulkan SDK you don't need to update your project files, and they'll work on other machines that might have different versions installed.

In the long run I'd recommend switching to CMake for project generation, rather than maintaining Visual Studio project files directly.  With CMake, adding a Vulkan dependency to your application is as easy as doing this:

```
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(MyApp Vulkan::Vulkan)
```

You can find existing CMake-based Vulkan examples [here](https://github.com/jherico/Vulkan) or [here](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan).

Comment: `VK_SDK_PATH` is deprecated.